# Pass serilaized object as parameter to HTTPServer in Java

Tags: java, web-services, httpserver

How can I pass a serilaized object as a param in a GET request to my HTTPServer? Please let me know as I have been unable to find a way to do the same.

Comment: Convert the serialized bytes to be hexadecimal encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    oos.writeObject(obj);
    oos.close();
    String prm = URLEncoder.encode(new String(bos.toByteArray(), "ISO-8859-1"), "ISO-8859-1");
```

On the server side:

```
servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
String s = servletRequeset.getParameter("obj");
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
Object obj = ois.readObject();
```

It's also possible to use Base64 instead of URL Encoding, the main idea is to pass serialized bytes in URL

Comment: Hi many thanks for your reply. One small doubt, how ll I be able to deserialize it back once I get this data in my service handler class?

Comment: Hi, am having a `HttpExchange` object on my server side. How to get params out using that? I didn't get what is servletRequest here. Sorry am very new to this. thanks.